# iframe load failure again

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a question similar to that posed in the [Detect failure to load contents of an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/375710/2065237) issue.  I am putting together a web page that loads a Google calendar as an iframe.  I know that a large number of the computers that will use my web page will have restricted internet access such that the Google calendar won't load into the iframe.  I would like to put a "timer" into my page that stops trying to load the Google calendar after a set amount of time or attempts and instead loads a local page that says the calendar can't be accessed.

I have been trying to use the `checkForContents()` function described previously, but I have now realized that I can't get any of the object properties from the Google site.  In other words, `document.getElementById(iframe).contentWindow.document` returns nothing (or at least nothing useful) and the function fails silently but totally.  I can instead use `document.getElementById(iframe).contentWindow`  which simply returns "[object Window]" (and I don't seem to be smart enough to do anything useful with that).

Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

reasons of security sandbox, you can not reach or modify any content if the domains are different

Comment: I understand the issue of different domains.  I'm looking for some way to solve the fundamental problem of testing that the frame hasn't loaded.

Comment: well use innerHTML to load a iframe :

div.innerHTML = "<iframe src="stackoverflow.com" onload="myLoadFunc()" onerror="myLoadErrorFunc()" />"

maybe this helps

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give it a shot.  But not today - other things are more pressing.