# jQuery.error() is not working for iframe.

Tags: jquery, iframe

I'm trying to use jquery to detect whether an `iframe` fails to load or the page doesn't exist, but the code below isn't working:

```
$('#frame').error(function(){
    //code here
});
```

Comment: Which piece of documentation led you to believe that this should work?

Comment: I just guessed, since it worked for img tags. Sadly, I'm restricted to not using php, so I'm kinda at a bottleneck right now

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal The part where its supposed to work for elements and iframe is an element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the comments on [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/error/) says:

> Using .error() on an iframe never seems to trigger (even though
>   .load() will trigger on a successful iframe load).

This event does not appear to be designed to work in this use case.

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375710/detect-failure-to-load-contents-of-an-iframe) explain how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

iframe do not trigger onerror event even if it fails to load the document. I think load will be triggered even in this case and you can check for the status code to determine if the page is loaded successfully or no.