# Check if JS has access to an iframe's document

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, same-origin-policy

Is there any standard way to know if my script has access to an `iframe`'s document?

I couldn't find anything in the web so I came up with this:

```js
function checkifr() {
    function errHandler() {
        alert('Error. Try again later.');
    }
    var ifr = $('#ifr')[0]; //the iframe DOM element

    try {
        var d = ifr.contentWindow || ifr.contentDocument;
        if (!d) {
            errHandler();
            return false;
        }

        var b = $('#ifr').contents().find('body');
        //... manipulate iframe content

    } catch(e) {
        errHandler();
    }
}
```

It works, Firefox throws an error when I try to access the `iframe`'s contents and ends up in the `catch` block. Chrome shows an `Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame` warning in the console but never enters the `catch` block, it seems to return `null` for those attempts so the initial `if (!d)` takes care of it. Opera and IE behave similarly to FF. **Edit:** With the code above, now Chrome returns an "empty" Window object (with no properties) which do not trigger my `if` block. Check [Esailija](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11873391/1331430)'s answer which works nicely cross-browser!

Here's the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/LHjwZ/6/).

I **can't** test the `iframe`'s `src` against `window.location`.

> **Justificatory Background:** This is because this function is part of a small image upload plugin which I'm developing (using an `iframe` as target since IE<9 doesn't support XHR2), and the goal is mainly validating connection error/timeout/etc. The default browser pages for these errors are subject to the same origin police, hence the purpose of this question. I don't want to send an ajax call to check if the page is available, as I want to validate the submit request itself. jQuery's [.load](https://stackoverflow.com/q/375710/1331430) handler doesn't fire for errors, jQuery's [.error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6867890/1331430) and the `onerror` HTML attribute do not work for this. An illustration of the working script is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/XqVtG/2/), but you may ignore it completely and simply answer the question below.

Note that the above block is solely for illustrating why I can't use the `iframe.src`.

I do think that there should an easier/standard way to check an `iframe`'s "accessibleness", but I can't find anything in the web nor SO except half-solutions which simply check the `iframe.src` and do not apply for many cases. If my hackish `try`/`catch` block is considered a technically "clean" solution, others may re-use it if no better option is found.

So is there any standard or simpler way or jQuery plugin to check if my script has access to an `iframe`'s document without comparing the `iframe`'s `src` with the `window.location`? Without `try`/`catch` blocks and errors/warnings in the console if possible.

Comment: `.documentWindow`? Which browser implements this?

Comment: oh yea, it should be `.contentWindow`

Comment: Pretty sure I took that part from another answer in SO, but nice find! `documentWindow` returns undefined in all browsers I've tested.. I'll look for the answer to check if this was a typo.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo on my part, thanks @ŠimeVidas and Esa!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's another option, can't really do it without try catch.

Tests http://jsfiddle.net/LHjwZ/11/

```
function checkIframe( ifr ) {
    var key = ( +new Date ) + "" + Math.random();

    try {
        var global = ifr.contentWindow;
        global[key] = "asd";
        return global[key] === "asd";
    }
    catch( e ) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, trying to set a var in the iframe's `contentWindow` looks much more cleaner than my code and is easily added to an abstraction level. +1, sec while I read the other answers and test them. `=]`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté the `if` was redudant as well because it would throw an error on `global[key]` if it was `null` or `undefined`

Comment: Yup makes perfect sense, setting a window property named with the miliseconds timestamp concatenated with `Math.random()` seems a little overkill, but it's a sign of the code's pr0ness without a doubt!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one idea that will work whether the accesses throw an exception or not:

```
function checkFrameAccess(ifr) {
    try {
        var doc = ifr.contentDocument || ifr.contentWindow.document;
        var origClass = doc.body.className;
        var newClass = origClass += " xxxxx";
        doc.body.className = newClass;
        var valid = doc.body.className == newClass;
        doc.body.className = origClass;
        return(valid);
    } catch(e) {
        return(false);
    }
}
```

If they throw an exception, you end up in the exception handler and return `false`.  If they don't throw an exception, then you test whether you can actually modify the className of the body tag in the frame.  If the modification works, then apparently, you could modify it. If not, then it wouldn't let you access it.

Comment: -1 not enough jQuery. Seriously now, your answer is clean and understandable.  +1 for answering before Esailija.