# Angularjs e2e test - How to use input(name).enter(value)?

Tags: testing, angularjs, jasmine

I'm so new in writing scenarios for `e2e` testing in `Angularjs`. I want to write a scenario to test the login. I have a form which has an email field as follow:

```
<input type="email" placeholder="Enter your e-mail" name="email" ng-model="form.email" value="" required autofocus >
```

And in my scenario I'm having having the following line which tries to pass some email address to that input field:

```
input('form.email').enter('blabla@blabla.com');
```

But unfortunately I'me getting the following error after running the test:
*6ms    input 'form.email' enter 'blabla@blabla.com'

Selector [ng\:model="form.email"] did not match any elements.*
Any suggestion?

Comment: I'm not seeing any problem in this example: http://plnkr.co/edit/yyF0YWIQ1zq0gMMwMv4X Can you produce an example which fails?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After checking your example, I found out my problem is not regarding input(name), Seems like I cant give the correct address in browser().navigateTo('../../partials/login.html'). I just wonder why it shows 'browser navigate to '../../views/login.html' in green if it cant navigate to that page!!!

Comment: I've had a go but I can't trap the error: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6867890 which says it doesn't apear to be possible.

Answer (score 0):

check to make sure that you have:

```
browser().navigateTo('/');
```

Without navigating first angular does not have any reference to the DOM.

You can also use :

```
pause();
```

To see exactly what the browser is displaying at the given time when running an e2e test.