# Determining when contents of an IFrame has loaded

Tags: javascript, events, iframe

NB: I don't believe this is a duplicate of [Detect failure to load contents of an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375710/detect-failure-to-load-contents-of-an-iframe) or [Detecting when Iframe content has loaded (Cross browser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751435/detecting-when-iframe-content-has-loaded-cross-browser) (or any of the similar ones).

In short I'm using an IFrame to display Pdfs using the browsers' internal viewer. Since we only support Chrome/FF (we use WebGL) and both have an embedded Pdf viewer, it's a convenient way to avoid implementing [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/) (at least until we need more control / can spare the resource).

That said, we do want to be able to detect when the IFrame has finished loading so we can transition properly/detect problems.

So, assuming the IFrame source is a pdf (and the pdf is coming from the same domain), is there any way to determine when the iframe has loaded *from the outside* ?

Comment: have you tried onload on iframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use onload event of iframe.Simple

```
<iframe src="test.pdf" onload="alert('Worked')" ></iframe>
```

Comment: Obviously - that's what I was doing. There's a slight issue in the onload fires twice - once when the iframe element is added to the DOM, the second time when the actual contents are loaded (probably a side-effect of setting the src later using Js) but I can work around that by binding the handler later. Thanks