# easyui how to set a event on load tab error

Tags: jquery-easyui

I'm use easyui tabs load html content:

```
contents.tabs('add',{
    title: title,
    href: href,
    closable: true,
    extractor:function(data){
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    }           
});
```

sometime I maybe got a 404, 500 response, but the response error message is not display in the new window. The tab window always show **loading style**.

So I try to find a **onLoadError**  event to catch this error in office manual: http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/tabs.php , but not exists. Please tell me how to do let me exit the loading status.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is so simple as it sounds.

If it is your server (not cross domain)  :

- If this is iframe tab: you might want to handle this onAdd and [check the iframe status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375710/detect-failure-to-load-contents-of-an-iframe)  before you expose it to the user.
- if it is ajax request, again, same thing, onload [check the status of the ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344145/how-to-get-response-status-code-from-jquery-ajax)

if it is not your domain (cross domain)

- You cant do much about it

But overall I dont think there is such functionality because of security reasons overhead.