Search Return if nothing found
i found this script `
<input type="number" id="zip" />
<button onClick="goTo()">Go</button>


<script>
function goTo() {
    var zip = document.getElementById('zip').value;
  window.location.replace("http://site-to-redirect.com/" + zip);
}
</script>

and I altered the last line to this:
window.frames["iframe"].location.assign(zip + ".html");

which places the corosponding html file into an iframe, which works wonderfully as long as theres a matching .html for the related input.
the original can be found here:
https://jsfiddle.net/fmontes/h6o4c9qy/4/
However, is there a way to modify this to show a specific page (i.e - noresult.html) if improper search (or typo) is entered?
ADDON::
the debugger gives this error:
"ReferenceError: $ is not defined"
so I added the following:
  if ( goTo() === "$ is not defined") {
       window.frames["iframe"].location.assign("noresult" + ".html");
}

....without success

Not sure why this got out of Staging Ground with two duplicate votes but it still looks like this answers your question: How to check if iframe is loaded or it has a content?.

Also this: Detect failure to load contents of an iframe

What is value in value.result? Also, if it exists at all, is it guaranteed to be the string "false" rather than a boolean false? student.value seems more sensible, except student is already document.getElementById('student').value. So student.value should be document.getElementById('student').value.value which doesn't make sense. Also, even iif it was just document.getElementById('student').value, then you shouldn't get the string "null"  again. document.getElementById('student') can return the value null but not a string.

In addition, there is no jQuery here. I don't see why the tag was used.

I've tried several variations - don't try variations: use the debugger.  See what value is before trying to see what it's properties are.   Same for student

As it's "only" an .html, you could go with the fetch option to see if it exists, eg: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76514876/2181514

And if you do a fetch, then don't bother with an iFrame unless the CSS is really different. Just load the result into a "student div". Make sure to look into "debounce" to give the person typing half a second to stop typing before you hammer the server looking for f,fr,fra,fran,frank
